# Gridview not allowing paging

Tags: asp.net, gridview, visual-web-developer-2010

I have a gridview on a asp web page and the formatting works fine except when I add AllowPaging or if I set the location of the gridview.  Here is the gridview code that I am using.

```
<asp:GridView 
ID="gridview01" 
runat="server" 
SkinId="Professional" 
AllowPaging="true"
CellPadding="4" 
EnableModelValidation="True" 
ForeColor="#333333" 
GridLines="None" 
Height="179px" 
Width="496px" 
style="margin-right: 0px"> 
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
</asp:GridView>
```

The top portion is just laid out like that so that I could read it easier. The gridview is populated when a button is pressed.  There is code behind the button that calls the query based on the input of two drop down lists.

Comment: What is the problem? Error or it just does not show pages of data?

Comment: It just doesn't show the page.  If I take out the paging it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use THis Code at BackEnd For Paging in Grid or ListView

```
protected void Grid_PagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
{

   GridDataPager1.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);

    BindGridView();

}
```